# How can we order and section (sort) dynamic UITable with NSDate in Swift?

Tags: swift, uitableview, nsdate, dynamic-tables

I want to know that if there any way we can order and section dynamic UITable with NSDate in Swift? (From present to past)

For example, I want dynamic table like this:

```
Section: 2015-06-04
2015-06-04 23:16:24
2015-06-04 22:46:23
2015-06-04 21:03:45

Section: 2015-06-02
2015-06-02 18:34:23
2015-06-02 12:05:45

Section: 2015-06-01
2015-06-01 07:34:23
2015-06-01 06:05:41
```

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSDate conforms to the `compare:` selector, so sort the backing mutable arrays with one of the sorting methods and reload the table data

Comment: And how can I get my whole table as an array? :)

Comment: I was assuming that you're using an Array as the data source for your UITableView

Comment: It is stored in Core Data, i'm not sure if it is a kind of array?

Comment: sorry, I don't know much about CoreData, but you would have to fetch your data using one of the fetch methods and put it into an array to be able to populate the table view

Comment: I append some array into a father array `var scoreLogOrderedArray:[NSArray] = []` and I tried code: `var mytest = scoreLogOrderedArray.sorted({ $0 > $1 })`. But it said `cannot invoke sorted with an arugement list of type '((_, _) -> _)`. So how can I solve that?

Comment: easier: example with a array of int, works also with NSDate: var array = [1, 6, 2, 9, 4, 8]    array.sort {$0 < $1}

Comment: yes, but how can I pass other data beside my time. I have to pass some string etc.

Comment: there are many tutorials how to use UITableView in Swift with a data model, for example [link](http://makeapppie.com/2014/07/12/swift-swift-how-to-use-uitableview-in-swift/)